# How to replicate a shortcode inside template

Tags: php, woocommerce, twig

In wordpress functions.php file I have a shortcode that allows me to display the order ID when I'm on the view-order.php page. The shortcode works fine.

What I am trying to do is find a more comfortable alternative to this. So I would like to take advantage of the Twig template, so I'm doing some testing. I'm actually viewing the order ID, but it stays the same for every order I decide to view.

Example:

- if I view the order 001, the ID 001 is shown (correct)
- if I view the order 002, the ID 001 is shown (incorrect)

With the shortcode this does not happen, I can correctly display the ID of each order. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

I've already done the same thing with my-orders page and my-downloads page, it worked fine, but for some reason it's not working with view-order.php page.

I appreciate any response, thanks.

```
add_shortcode( 'view_order_id' , 'view_order_00' );
function view_order_00(){
 $order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );
 $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
 return $order->get_id();
}
```

```
{% set post = system.get.order_id|php('get_post') %}
{% set order = post.ID|php('wc_get_order') %}
{% for item in order.get_items %}
{% for download in order.get_downloadable_items %}

<div>{{post.ID}}</div>
  
{%endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure why are you are outputting `post.ID` when you want the order id. Did you try `order.get_id()`?

Comment: The word "post" is only defining the variable of the previous line. For example, I can replace with anything and I always get the same result: `{% set x = system.get.order_id | php ('get_post')%}` `{% set order = x.ID | php ('wc_get_order')%}`

I don't know if that changes anything. Anyway I tried with order.get_id but I'm not getting any results.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a third party plugin called e-addons, this offers many widgets for elementor, including Twig Template.

I contacted plugin support and they told me that I would have to pass the order ID in $ _GET to fix the problem. Furthermore, all this must be done in a dedicated elementor page and not in the view-order.php template as I was doing initially.

So here is a brief explanation of what I did step by step to fix the problem. I hope it will be useful to anyone who has had the same difficulties as me.

**1**. I created a new page with elementor titled test page. The

**2**. I copied the permalink of the newly created page (test-page) and put it in a filter in the functions.php file, here it is below.

```
// When you click on view order, this filter allows you to redirect from view-order (original woocommerce endpoint) to a custom page created with elementor.
function filter_woocommerce_get_endpoint_url( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ) {
    
    // Specific endpoint: If in the advanced settings of woocommerce you have changed the endpoint view order, then below you have to replace view-order with the one you have chosen in the advanced settings wi WC
    if ( $endpoint === 'view-order' ) {
    
    // New URL: change test-page with permalink of the page you created earlier. The /?order_id= part should not be removed.
    $url = $permalink . 'test-page/?order_id=' . $value;
} 
return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'filter_woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 10, 4 );
```

**3**. After setting the filter with the permalink we need to modify the new page with elementor. Once in the editor I selected the e-Addons Posts Query widget and dragged it to the page area.

Step 3 opens here, follow these steps to configure the widget correctly, only change what is mentioned below:

Go to the Query Tab of the query posts widget

*Query*

- In query type **select Post Type**
- In options> post type **select order**
- in post status **select Any**

*Query Filter*

- in "By" **select Meta Key**

in Mtakey Filters add new and modify as follows

- in Post Field custom meta key **select _customer_user**
- in Value Type **select Numeric**
- in Compare operator **select "="**
- in Post Field Value **select User Field**

If you do everything correctly in step 3, the user will be able to view the orders, otherwise if you do something wrong you get nothing.
Here ends step 3.

**4**. Then go to the first tab of the widget entitled Content. Here you have to go to the menu item titled Post Items, and this is where I played with the Twig template. So the code I originally posted in my question now works.

```
{% set post = system.get.order_id|php('get_post') %}
{% set order = post.ID|php('wc_get_order') %}
{% for item in order.get_items %}
{% for download in order.get_downloadable_items %}

<div>{{post.ID}}</div>
  
{%endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, when I am on the order history page and click on view order I am redirected correctly to the specific order page which for example is mywebsite.com/account/test-page?order_id=xxxxxx